# How to enable the mousetrap.js to accept Caps letter

Tags: capslock

I am using [mousetrap.js](https://github.com/ccampbell/mousetrap) library to accept the possible characters. But It is not accepting capital letters when caps is on while it is working fine with Alt+any letter.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was using this library until we decided to remove it as a dependency.  I'm programming around it now.  I'm not sure it actually handles caps lock, though.  This [caps lock state] seems to be a really poorly supported attribute in JS.  Most of the methods i've looked at for detecting caps lock don't actually work on a Mac.  event.key seems to work with caps lock in FireFox, but is undefined in Chrome and Safari.